# Menu Selection Console

Tags: c#, console

Current code: C# Sharp
If this can be done another play i'm open to that also.
Project current code: https://github.com/Haetrox/Project/blob/main/CS

I am wanting to make a console window that has the main menu then has submenus.
In one of the submenus I want to have the question with a list of options, have the user select the options, receive another question, respond, and end up with the console replying back with what their choices were.

Goal:
What medications do you need today?
BP
H1. Atenelol H2. Lisinopril
Diabetes
D1. Metformin D2. Gabapentin
Thyroid
T1. Synthroid T2. Levothyroxine
Other
O1.
Please List the Choices: "H2, D1, T1, O1"
Other was selected, please type what medications: "Cyclobenzaprine"
Do you have the bottles with you today?
Please Respond Y/N: "No"
Have we prescribed the medication in the last year?
Please Respond Y/N: "Yes"
You are requesting a refill on "Lisinopril, Metformin, Synthroid, Cyclobenzaprine"

I am struggling to figure out how to make this possible. I was using the switch method to move to the other menus but it doesn’t seem to work for multiple selections.
Can someone review the code and help me figure out how to make this happen? Everything I find is for a singular writeline and reply.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Still wondering how to do this. Again if anyone has suggestions I am open.